# A vast sea containing large air pockets that form into rings around the world: will this make sense?

Tags: science-fiction

I want to know if this will make sense for my readers, in my book the world is deformed and humans have evolved to live at the bottom of the sea (which is all the world has become, a large sea). I'm having trouble explaining the concept.

Comment: It would not make sense

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuildingSE, and you're right. As of now I can think of many things you could mean but I can't pinpoint a most likely candidate. How about trying to add some more details? E.g. Some of your thoughts regarding how it'd work or what you'd want to so with it? :)

Comment: Have a read about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Integral_Trees for inspiration

Comment: I would some clarity on what it meant by "rings" , are they underwater?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, at some point in the past, the seas started raising, just like in [Waterworld](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waterworld). With 2 things different:

1. It happened long before people knew how to build skyscrapers.
2. The bottom of the sea is just 3-6 meters deep.

And so the humankind build communities in dome-shaped buildings, and adapted to live  under the surface of the water (but in close confinements). Each building has is way to get air (and Oxygen in particular) - maybe plants, maybe an opening at the water level (like a chimney). Maybe they buy it in huge canisters, made from special whale skin?

Getting from one settlement to another will require a submarine or a boat (and that the settlement will have an opening at the water level).

People will have low vitamin D levels and their eyes will adapt to the low-light. Maybe they also adapt to consume less Oxygen?

Answer (score 2):

There are spiders that build air bubbles underwater to stay there longer ( https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diving_bell_spider ), so you might assume the world has turned into vast ocean as a result of global climate change and looks now similar to https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Interior_Seaway . Spiders evolved to be much bigger and we're domesticated by humans who now are using them to build dwellings underwater (most seas where humans live would be shallow, no plausible and air bell in twilight of midnight zones possible)

Answer (score 1):

The process of *buoyancy* cause gas to float above liquid (as gases are usually much lighter than liquids) - so what's keeping the air down there. Also, under any great depth of water the pressure changes the point of chemical equilibria leading to effects like nitrogen narcosis in humans.

Answer (score 0):

If the world is all ocean, as in there is no rocky core, then this would work. People's bodies can float in the ocean, therefore you would expect them to be near the top of it. You can make the ocean more salty or the people less dense if you want to make them more floaty.

Then an atmosphere is formed around the planet, so there is an air/sea interface. People will be pulled by buoyancy up from the sea to the air/sea interface, and pulled by gravity down from the air to the air sea interface.

No assume, that people can get a hold of floating building materials (seaweed, leviathan bones that are less dense than seawater, etc). How they can build structures and civilization at the interface.

This gives you a huge planetary ocean and a 'shell' of air going around the world. If you want to turn the shell into a ring, you can just break physics and flatten the sphere of the earth into a disk, or stretch it into an infinite cylinder or something